# Is there a way to use XCode to create ASP .NET files?

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xcode

I have heard about C# for IOS development using Xamarin tool.I want to know that is there any support for .Net framework in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

No way to combine `.Net framework` with `XCode IDE`.

However you can write .Net languages with `Mono framework` for `OSX`.

Here is mono website you can learn.

http://www.mono-project.com/

Answer (score 0):

Run a vm with xp and an older visual studio (for web development) version. I just had to bust out a project and I learned it and turned in my finished product in a week. Such a convenient easy-to-use IDE.

Comment: he is talking about the combination of XCode with .Net in Mac. (not visual studio with VMWare).

Comment: Visual Studio is the *best* for (non-mono) .NET development. There are free "Express" versions, which may or may not provide all that is required, and it can add up: More memory ($200) + VM ($50-70) + Windows ($50-$150) + VS (maybe non-free required) + ReSharper .. but this doesn't say how to do it "from XCode".

Comment: dude i know what he's talking about. i should i began my answer with a "not that i know of, but here's a better way to go"